# Batch Command Error

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
@echo off
setlocal
set Folder=C:\Test
set FileMask=*.txt
set OldestFile=
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /o:d %Folder%\%FileMask%" 2^>NUL') do (
    set OldestFile=%%a
    goto Break
)
:Break
if "%OldestFile%"=="" (
    echo No files found in '%Folder%' matching '%FileMask%'!
) else (
    del "%Folder%\%OldestFile%"
)
```

Hi, I am trying to delete the oldest file in the Test directory using batch file but I am getting an error after running it with or without an Admin Privilege where ***'dir /b /o:d "C\Test" 2>NUL' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*** I am trying to run it on Windows Server 2012 R2 x64 bit. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Missing `"` in the `dir` command before `%folder%`. Also I believe if you want the **oldest** you'd need `/o:-d` and I'd add `/a-d` to exclude the possibility of a hit on a directoryname.

Comment: Hello @Magoo, i tried adding " before %folder% and /a-d but still getting the same error.

Comment: If `dir` isn't working for you, you probably did something to mess up your PATH variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell seems a bit more concise. Once you are satisfied that it is deleting the correct file, remove the `-WhatIf` switch.

```
C:\src\t>type xxx.bat
@ECHO OFF
SET "Folder=C:\src\t"
SET "FileMask=*.txt"

powershell -noprofile -command "dir %Folder% -filt %FileMask% -file |"^
    "sort -p LastWriteTime -d |"^
    "select -l 1 |"^
    "del -WhatIf"

C:\src\t>xxx.bat
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "C:\src\t\th.txt".
```

If you are running PowerShell, the syntax is much cleaner.

```
PS C:\src\t> type .\xxx.ps1
$Folder = 'C:\src\t'
$FileMask = '*.txt'

Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Filter $FileMask -File |
    Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending |
    Select-Object -Last 1 |
    Remove-Item -WhatIf
PS C:\src\t> .\xxx.ps1
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "C:\src\t\th.txt".
```

Comment: There is absolutely nothing clean about that syntax.

Comment: @lit how about deleting the oldest file in a zip file?

Comment: @IamBayMax - Deleting from an archive needs to be another question.